# Class from Base Class with null properties

Tags: c#

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IResponse<T> {
  IList<Error> Errors { get; }
  IPaging Paging { get; }
  IList<T> Result { get; }    
}
```

And the its implementation:

```
public class Response<T> : IResponse<T> {

  IList<Error> Errors { get; private set; }
  public IPaging Paging { get; private set; }
  public IList<T> Result { get; private set; }

  public Response(IList<T> result, IPaging paging, IList<Error> errors) {
    Errors = errors;
    Paging = paging;
    Result = result;
  }

}
```

So I use it as follows:

```
Response<MyModel> response = new Response<MyModel>();
```

In some situations I need to create a response where I do not have a T and Paging and Result are null ... They are null but still exist in object.

```
Response response = new Response();
```

With what I have it wont's work (I think. In these case there isn't a model):

```
Response<?> response = new Response<?>();
```

The reason for this is that I will convert response to JSON and I still want Paging and Result to appear.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `new Response<object>(null, null, null)` ?  Or provide empty lists and a 'null object' that implements `IPaging`.  It's not entirely clear what you mean by 'they are null but still exist in object'.

Comment: "they are null but still exist in the class" ... So when I transform to Json both paging and result still appear as properties but null.

Comment: If the properties aren't appearing in your output, you probably need to adjust your JSON serialization settings to always include nulls. Assuming you're using Newtonsoft: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm

Comment: The big question is how do you serialize Response<?> into json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to make any code changes to your models if you're using Newtonsoft for serialization, you can do something like the following:

```
void Main() {
    Response<MyResponse> myResponse = new Response<MyResponse>(new List<MyResponse>(), null, null);
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    using(var writer = new StringWriter(sb)) {
        using (var jWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer)) {
            serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            serializer.Serialize(jWriter, myResponse);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}

public interface IResponse<T> {
  IList<Error> Errors { get; }
  IPaging Paging { get; }
  IList<T> Result { get; }    
}

public class Response<T> : IResponse<T> {

  public IList<Error> Errors { get; private set; }
  public IPaging Paging { get; private set; }
  public IList<T> Result { get; private set; }

  public Response(IList<T> result, IPaging paging, IList<Error> errors) {
    Errors = errors;
    Paging = paging;
    Result = result;
  }

}

public class Error {


}

public interface IPaging {

}

public class MyResponse {
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Running the above code results in the following output:

```
{"Result":[]}
```

By changing the serializer setting on this line:

```
serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

to

```
serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
```

The result becomes:

```
{"Errors":null,"Paging":null,"Result":[]}
```